# How do I run a game with a .x86 extension

Tags: games, dynamic-linking

Can anyone help me run the game cs portable, I used to play this all the time on windows?? it's free and the download link is [here](http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/CSPortable_Vile),
the download link is in the bottom of his profile description.

The file extension is .x86 and the game is only 45MB, so it won't take long too download.

Comment: And one more note: suggesting users to download binaries from some website isn't a very well received practice. I'm not sure about others but I'm not running anything I don't need and especially not a binary from a site I don't trust.

Answer (score 4):

Linux is like a honey badger and honey badgers don't care. Especially about file extensions :)

It's hard to tell whether this is a developer's fault without more info. It looks like you're running something that didn't come as a package that's part of Ubuntu. This could be statically or dynamically linked against some libraries.

You can find out by running:
`file /path/to/the/file.x86`
if this is script as opposed to a binary, you need to find what's the actual binary it executes by looking at it.

This is important since "statically" means you probably don't have to install any dependencies to be able to run it. Dynamically means that your system needs to have certain libraries installed before you can run the binary.

If it's a binary, you can find out if it's a dynamically or statically linked by running

`ldd /path/to/the/file.x86`

Example of a dynamically linked binary:

```
 ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff631ff000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fed8fe35000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fed8fc31000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fed8f871000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fed90082000)
```

While a statically linked binary would show something along the lines:

```
not a dynamic executable
```

One other thing to keep in mind - if you're clicking the file in order to execute it, if it crashes, or just terminates, you won't know what caused it since you don't see the output.

You could try opening a terminal, entering the directory where you have this binary, and running it with `./file.x86`. The './' is important here since it means 'in the current directory'. This way you can see any error or informational messages when it terminates and possibly there's some hint about what you need to do in order to make it work.

In other words, check your game's requirements.

Comment: Gave you a +1 because honey badgers don't care ^^.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the binary file has **"execute permission"**...
The easy way , right click in the file, then *properties*, go to the *permissions* tab and click in the *"Allow executing file as program".*

[image]

or by command line:

```
chmod +x /path/to/the/file.x86
```

Then double click in the binary file or go to the path (in my case is **/home/user/Dowloads/262linux)** .
in the terminal and type:

```
cd /home/user/Downloads/262linux

./262e.x86
```

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: Hahahah unfortunately the game doesn't even work :(    Is this a fault of the game developer?

Answer (score -1):

For more information:

**The [Unity3D Game Engine](http://unity3d.com) exports Linux game builds to these file types (.x86 & .x86_64).**

I encountered this problem today with my first Linux build in Unity (I am a Unity3D developer), but it's easily solvable, as explained in the answers above.

Just thought you'd like to know.

Cheers.